# Existence of an open dense of a connected scheme such that the preimage under a surjective finite etale map is connected

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $K$ be a field, $G$ a smooth finite linear algebraic group over $K$, $X$ a proper reduced connected separated scheme of finite type over $K$, $g: Y \to X$ a connected etale $G$-torsor over $X$ (so in particular $g$ is finite surjective and etale). Is the following statement true

> For any (Zariski) open dense $U \subset X$ there exists an open dense $V \subset X$ contained in $U$ such that $g^{-1}(V)$ is connected.

If not, what additional conditions can we put on $X$ so that it becomes true?

Comment: This is automatic if $X$ is normal (or more generally geometrically unibranch), for then so is $Y$, so any open in $X$ or $Y$ is irreducible if and only if it is connected, and a nonempty open in an irreducible is irreducible. To see that it fails already for nodal curves, look at Figure 12 in Exercise III.10.6 in Hartshorne (take $U$ the complement of the node).